# pppd: LCP terminated by peer (peer refused to authenticate)

Tags: vpn

I'm confused, VPN client worked flawlessly on my virtual machine and today when I tried it failed to connect to L2TP VPN server... This is the log from my client VM, can someone help? I changed nothing (on purpose) and I do not understand why suddenly peer does not want to authenticate and was that expected in the past or its a new thing? My tablet still manage to connect as before.

```
Sep  4 22:29:51 ubuntu64 ipsec_setup: ...Openswan IPsec started
Sep  4 22:29:51 ubuntu64 L2tpIPsecVpnControlDaemon: Command ipsec setup start finished with exit code 0
Sep  4 22:29:51 ubuntu64 L2tpIPsecVpnControlDaemon: Executing command service xl2tpd start
Sep  4 22:29:51 ubuntu64 xl2tpd[4665]: setsockopt recvref[30]: Protocol not available
Sep  4 22:29:51 ubuntu64 ipsec__plutorun: adjusting ipsec.d to /etc/ipsec.d
Sep  4 22:29:51 ubuntu64 xl2tpd[4665]: This binary does not support kernel L2TP.
Sep  4 22:29:51 ubuntu64 L2tpIPsecVpnControlDaemon: Command service xl2tpd start finished with exit code 0
Sep  4 22:29:51 ubuntu64 pluto: adjusting ipsec.d to /etc/ipsec.d
Sep  4 22:29:51 ubuntu64 xl2tpd[4666]: xl2tpd version xl2tpd-1.3.6 started on ubuntu64 PID:4666
Sep  4 22:29:51 ubuntu64 xl2tpd[4666]: Written by Mark Spencer, Copyright (C) 1998, Adtran, Inc.
Sep  4 22:29:51 ubuntu64 xl2tpd[4666]: Forked by Scott Balmos and David Stipp, (C) 2001
Sep  4 22:29:51 ubuntu64 xl2tpd[4666]: Inherited by Jeff McAdams, (C) 2002
Sep  4 22:29:51 ubuntu64 xl2tpd[4666]: Forked again by Xelerance (www.xelerance.com) (C) 2006
Sep  4 22:29:51 ubuntu64 xl2tpd[4666]: Listening on IP address 0.0.0.0, port 1701
Sep  4 22:29:51 ubuntu64 ipsec__plutorun: 002 added connection description "CBER_L2TP_CABLE"
Sep  4 22:29:51 ubuntu64 L2tpIPsecVpnControlDaemon: Executing command ipsec auto --ready
Sep  4 22:29:52 ubuntu64 ipsec__plutorun: 002 added connection description "CBER_L2TP_ADSL"
Sep  4 22:29:52 ubuntu64 L2tpIPsecVpnControlDaemon: Command ipsec auto --ready finished with exit code 0
Sep  4 22:29:52 ubuntu64 L2tpIPsecVpnControlDaemon: Executing command ipsec auto --up CBER_L2TP_CABLE
Sep  4 22:29:52 ubuntu64 L2tpIPsecVpnControlDaemon: Command ipsec auto --up CBER_L2TP_CABLE finished with exit code 0
Sep  4 22:29:53 ubuntu64 L2tpIPsecVpnControlDaemon: Closing client connection
Sep  4 22:29:53 ubuntu64 xl2tpd[4666]: Connecting to host yin-cable.dyndns.biz, port 1701
Sep  4 22:29:55 ubuntu64 xl2tpd[4666]: Connection established to 999.999.999.999, 1701.  Local: 19801, Remote: 56042 (ref=0/0).
Sep  4 22:29:55 ubuntu64 xl2tpd[4666]: Calling on tunnel 19801
Sep  4 22:29:55 ubuntu64 xl2tpd[4666]: check_control: Received out of order control packet on tunnel 56042 (got 0, expected 1)
Sep  4 22:29:55 ubuntu64 xl2tpd[4666]: handle_packet: bad control packet!
Sep  4 22:29:55 ubuntu64 xl2tpd[4666]: check_control: Received out of order control packet on tunnel 56042 (got 0, expected 1)
Sep  4 22:29:55 ubuntu64 xl2tpd[4666]: handle_packet: bad control packet!
Sep  4 22:29:55 ubuntu64 xl2tpd[4666]: Call established with 999.999.999.999, Local: 5753, Remote: 13038, Serial: 1 (ref=0/0)
Sep  4 22:29:55 ubuntu64 xl2tpd[4666]: start_pppd: I'm running: 
Sep  4 22:29:55 ubuntu64 xl2tpd[4666]: "/usr/sbin/pppd" 
Sep  4 22:29:55 ubuntu64 xl2tpd[4666]: "passive" 
Sep  4 22:29:55 ubuntu64 xl2tpd[4666]: "nodetach" 
Sep  4 22:29:55 ubuntu64 xl2tpd[4666]: ":" 
Sep  4 22:29:55 ubuntu64 xl2tpd[4666]: "file" 
Sep  4 22:29:55 ubuntu64 xl2tpd[4666]: "/etc/ppp/CBER_L2TP_CABLE.options.xl2tpd" 
Sep  4 22:29:55 ubuntu64 xl2tpd[4666]: "/dev/pts/4" 
Sep  4 22:29:55 ubuntu64 pppd[4725]: Plugin passprompt.so loaded.
Sep  4 22:29:55 ubuntu64 pppd[4725]: pppd 2.4.5 started by root, uid 0
Sep  4 22:29:55 ubuntu64 pppd[4725]: Using interface ppp0
Sep  4 22:29:55 ubuntu64 pppd[4725]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/4
Sep  4 22:29:55 ubuntu64 NetworkManager[794]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
Sep  4 22:29:55 ubuntu64 NetworkManager[794]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0): no ifupdown configuration found.
Sep  4 22:29:55 ubuntu64 NetworkManager[794]: <warn> /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0: couldn't determine device driver; ignoring...
Sep  4 22:29:55 ubuntu64 pppd[4725]: LCP terminated by peer (peer refused to authenticate)
Sep  4 22:29:55 ubuntu64 xl2tpd[4666]: control_finish: Connection closed to 999.999.999.999, serial 1 ()
Sep  4 22:29:55 ubuntu64 xl2tpd[4666]: Terminating pppd: sending TERM signal to pid 4725
Sep  4 22:29:55 ubuntu64 pppd[4725]: Terminating on signal 15
Sep  4 22:29:55 ubuntu64 pppd[4725]: Modem hangup
Sep  4 22:29:55 ubuntu64 pppd[4725]: Connection terminated.
Sep  4 22:29:55 ubuntu64 NetworkManager[794]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
Sep  4 22:29:55 ubuntu64 pppd[4725]: Exit.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your L2TP client loose Your password durring connection. You had to add it in file with Your connection parameters for example bellow username phrase - password "Your_pass".

```
nano /etc/ppp/Your_connection_name.options.xl2tpd
```

and You should add at the bottom of file:

```
password "Your_pass"
```

But remember:

- it is not good idea to keep plain text passwords,
- after changing settings Your password will be overwriten and will dissapeare.

Comment: elcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)